# Android - Installing Couchbase

Tags: android, couchbase

If I am working with library project, where should the couchbase files be placed? in the library project or application project or anywhere? (coucbase files are the files mentioned in the "Installing Couchbase into your Application" section [here](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1**: Install the couchbase in the library project and add the `Couchbase Service` in the application project manifest file. I got the following error.

```
         V/ErlangThread(12394): {"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','/data/data/com.allogy.dpmarketplace/erlang/bin/start.boot'}}
```

**Case 2**: Install the couchbase in the application project and add the `OptErlang.jar` and `Couchbase.jar`to the library project and use the couchbase services in the library project. This works.

From whatever I have seen, the couchbase service can be installed in the application project Only and not the library project.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear from the instructions. These files have to be place in your "top-level folder" of your project.

That means, the root folder of your project,i.e, directly inside your project folder.

Comment: I have got 2 projects. One library project and one application project. Which project folder does it go in?

Comment: Depends on your projects. If it's only required for your app, put it inside your application project, else, if it has to be available for other projects, put it in the library project.